# Small question about vertices in hypergraphs

Tags: definition, hypergraphs

Say we have a hypergraph $H$ and a (hyper)edge $E$. Does that mean that all vertices in $E$ are connected?

So if $E= \{a,b,c\}$ does that necessarily mean $a$ and $b$ are connected?

And does that mean that every vertex is connected to it self?

Answer (score 2):

It, of course, depends on how you define "connected". For examples the usual definition of neighboring nodes is that there exists at least one edge between them. Under that definition, you can say that all nodes that belong to a hyperedge are neighbors of each other.